# UIView animation not working without UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

I encountered a weird bug (or I'm really stupid...):
I wanna display a custom callout in an MKAnnotationView.
What I'm doing is adding a custom view as a subview of the MKAnnotationView.
I'm having problems with the adding animation.

I have a MKMapView with my view controller as delegate

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
{
    [self.calloutViewController setCalloutState:CalloutStateNormal
                                       animated:YES
                                 annotationView:annotationView
                                     completion:NULL];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
{
    [self.calloutViewController setCalloutState:CalloutStateHidden
                                       animated:YES
                                 annotationView:annotationView
                                     completion:NULL];
}
```

self.calloutViewController is a custom view controller that creates a view with bubble shape (just adding round corners and white background).

```
- (void)setCalloutState:(CalloutState)calloutState
               animated:(BOOL)animated
         annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
             completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
{
    if (self.view.superview == annotationView || !annotationView) {

    } else {
//        [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];

        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, normalViewWidth, normalViewHeight);
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(annotationView.bounds.size.width / 2, 0);

        [annotationView addSubview:self.view];
    }

    void (^animationBlock)(void) = ^{
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        switch (calloutState) {
            case CalloutStateHidden:
                self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, normalViewWidth, normalViewHeight);
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
                break;
            case CalloutStateNormal:
                self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, normalViewWidth, normalViewHeight);
                break;
            case CalloutStateExpanded:
                self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, expandedViewWidth, expandedViewHeight);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        self.view.center = CGPointMake(annotationView.bounds.size.width / 2, 0);

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    };

    if (animated) {
        // TODO: figure out why the first animateWithDuration is needed in this nested thing
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:NULL
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                                   delay:0
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                              animations:animationBlock
                                              completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                  if (finished) {
                                                      self.calloutState = calloutState;

                                                      // TODO: figure out how to end UIView animation instantly so we don't need the second condition at the if
                                                      // having a concurrency problem here
                                                      if (calloutState == CalloutStateHidden && self.view.superview == annotationView) {
                                                          [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                                                      }

                                                      self.editingEnabled = calloutState == CalloutStateExpanded;
                                                  }

                                                  if (completion) {
                                                      completion(finished);
                                                  }
                                              }];

                         }];
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    } else {
        animationBlock();

        self.calloutState = calloutState;
        if (calloutState == CalloutStateHidden) {
            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        }

        self.editingEnabled = calloutState == CalloutStateExpanded;

        if (completion) {
            completion(YES);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is:
- If I select one pin (MKAnnotationView) on the map it animates correctly showing the callout bubble I created.
- After that I tap a different pin (while the bubble was still showing in the last one).
- Then with option 1) the callout bubble just jumps from one pin to another, without animating its scale.
- With option 2) it works just fine the way it is supposed to.

I wanna understand why option 1) doesn't work.
I don't think it should make any difference, since there is no animation going on when I tap the second pin.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Just to simplify, I've created a project with the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce my problem:

```
@interface TestViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *customCallout;

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.customCallout = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-50, -50, 100, 50)];
    self.customCallout.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    CustomAnnotation *annoation1 = [CustomAnnotation new];
    annoation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40, -100);
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annoation1];

    CustomAnnotation *annoation2 = [CustomAnnotation new];
    annoation2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40, -90);
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annoation2];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [self.customCallout removeFromSuperview];
    self.customCallout.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
    [view addSubview:self.customCallout];

//    [UIView animateWithDuration:0
//                          delay:0
//                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
//                     animations:NULL
//                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                               delay:0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.customCallout.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                          }
                                          completion:NULL];
//                     }];
}

@end
```

Just like before, the first time you tap one annotation, it works fine, but when you tap the second annotation the animation doesn't happen. If you uncomment the commented code, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` begins the animation from the current state *as drawn on screen*, not from the current value of the property. So, even though the view's `transform` property has a value of `Scale(0, 0)`, it hasn't drawn that to screen yet. The reason that the extra animation block makes a difference is that, even with a duration of 0, the completion isn't executed immediately, but rather on the next pass through the run loop, which gives the view enough time to draw itself.

If you remove the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option, the animation will work as expected:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [self.customCallout removeFromSuperview];
    self.customCallout.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
    [view addSubview:self.customCallout];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.customCallout.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
```

Comment: But I need the UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState in case some other animation is already happening, for example, selecting one pin, deselecting, and selecting again the same pin.

Comment: I actually only removeFromSuperview and set the transform to Scale(0, 0) if the customCallout is changing pins, in that case I want to remove it immediately from the pin that is selected, and display it with an animation to the new pin that is being selected.

Comment: Btw, thank you for your explanation, I think I understood the reason.
Is there anyway to make the transform Scale(0, 0) draw itself on screen? I mean, reflect the UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState ?

Comment: I just tried what you said and didn't work =/.
To be fair, I do change the frame (and center) in my actual code, not just the scale, and it animates in a weird way, not coming from the properties I set before the animation.

Comment: I was using your simplified example, and it worked. Once you set a transform, the value of `frame` is undefined, so setting it might not work as expected. Try setting `bounds` and `center` instead.

Comment: I'm setting the transform to CGAffineTransformIdentity before setting the frame, and I set the actual transform that I want after setting the frame. In that case it shouldn't matter if I set the bounds or the frame right?

Comment: Could you update your code to reflect the `frame` / `center` animations?

Comment: Sure, just updated with the actual code that I'm using. For now you can forget about the expanded state (I'm not having problems with it anyway).